# Why is R filtering not working for specific values?

Tags: r

I am struggling to understand why my R is behaving in a certain way. I've created a simple example below to show the issue.

```
x <- seq(0,2,0.05)
y <- seq(1,length(x))

z <- data.frame(x,y)
```

Now that the data frame z has been created, I am going to try filter for some values.
This first piece of code works exactly as expected:

```
z[z$x==1,]

   x  y
21 1 21
```

However the following doesn't work as expected:

```
z[z$x==1.2,]

x y
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Does anybody know why this is happening? The value 1.2 definitely exists in column x.

Comment: Read : [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Comment: It works for integers, but not for an arbitrary decimal! Read the link @Ronak Shah gave you! It explains everything!

Comment: Thanks all, this is really useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to tiny differences in the underlying floating point representation of the numbers in R. Look:

```
z[abs(z$x - 1.2) < 0.0000001,]
#>      x  y
#> 25 1.2 25
```

If you create the same sequence by dividing integers rather than sequentially adding 0.05 (which cannot be exactly represented in floating point) the equality now works:

```
x <- 0:40 / 20
which(x == 1.2)
#> [1] 25
```